# Whether a pointer to struct can directly assign value to struct's members?

Tags: c

//whether this code block on my textbook is wrong?
//I tried but failed to run and terminal shows segmentation fault.

```
typedef struct{
    _I num;
    _u32 p[];
}_BUF;
_BUF create_buf(_I size){
    void *p = malloc(size + sizeof(_BUF)));
    _BUF *pbuf;  // a pointer to _BUF 
    pbuf->p = p; // pbuf->p directly points allocated memory. 
    pbuf->num = size;
    return pbuf;
}
```

Comment: `pbuf` has **type** pointer to `_BUF`, but it's uninitialized so it doesn't point to any actual `_BUF` object.

Comment: The correct idiom here would be `_BUF *pbuf = malloc(size + sizeof(_BUF); pbuf->num = size; return pbuf;`. You do not need a `void *`. The member `p` of `_BUF` is an array, not a pointer, and you cannot assign to it.  The array exists at a particular location in memory that does not change.

Comment: By the way, identifiers starting with `_` and an upper-case letter are reserved in C and should not be used for your own types.  If your textbook does this, it had better have a very good reason.

Answer (score 1):

The flexible array member `p` of the `_BUF` type is not a pointer.  That array is always located immediately after the `num` member (with possibly a fixed amount of padding in between).  It is not possible to assign to an array object; you cannot make that array refer to memory somewhere else.

The `malloc(size + sizeof(_BUF))` allocates the memory for both at once.  So a correct implementation of this function would simply be

```
typedef struct{
    _I num;
    _u32 p[];
}_BUF;

_BUF *create_buf(_I size){
    _BUF *pbuf = malloc(size + sizeof(_BUF)));
    pbuf->num = size;
    return pbuf;
}
```

There is no need for an intermediary `void *`; even though `malloc` returns `void *`, you can and should convert the return value directly to the type you actually want, and no cast is required.

And, as Craig Estey points out, returning a `_BUF` by value makes no sense here; it needs to be a pointer.  Hopefully that was just a typo.

If the code you put in your question is really copied correctly from your textbook, then your textbook is talking nonsense, and you should probably get a better one.

Comment: Function return type `_BUF` --> `_BUF *`

Comment: @CraigEstey: Thanks, another nonsensical element from the original code that I copied without noticing.